# Test variable is bound and non-nil

Tags: elisp

Does something already exist to do this?

```
(defun good (var)
     (and (boundp 'var) var))
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a macro defined in `bindings.el` that does exactly that:

```
(defmacro bound-and-true-p (var)
  "Return the value of symbol VAR if it is bound, else nil."
  `(and (boundp (quote ,var)) ,var))
```

Answer (score 11):

How about this:

```
bound-and-true-p is a Lisp macro in `bindings.el'.

(bound-and-true-p VAR)

Return the value of symbol VAR if it is bound, else nil.
```